# How to get rid of yellow underlines of Polymer attributes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, polymer

Eclipse is spewing yellow underlines of [Polymer attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html). How do I get rid of this eyesore? I tried Window/Preferences/Validation but I don't want to disable HTML Syntax Validator for my project.

Incidentally, does Polymer provide its own validator in Eclipse?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: Using Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler)